# Why are some "Manuka honey" so cheap, like $1 USD/100 g?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Seasoned Advice post: [Why are some "Manuka honey" so cheap, like $1 USD/100 g?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/123603/why-are-some-manuka-honey-so-cheap-like-1-usd-100-g)

How can we rewrite [Why are some "Manuka honey" so cheap, like $1 USD/100 g?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/123603) to make it on topic?

I am not asking about ["the economics of food markets".](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/123603/why-are-some-manuka-honey-so-cheap-like-1-usd-100-g#comment202874_123603) ["The higher the [MGO] number, the more expensive your honey will be."](https://mountainvalleyhoney.co.nz/articles/why-is-manuka-honey-expensive-the-inside-story/) Perhaps there are different qualities of Manuka honey?

> [Within New Zealand you might find cheaper honey that is labelled Manuka but which doesn’t bear an MGO or UMF label. Be aware — it may contain *some* Manuka, but there is really no way to tell how much.](https://mountainvalleyhoney.co.nz/articles/why-is-manuka-honey-expensive-the-inside-story/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove all references to price.

The way companies choose to price their products is awfully complicated, and a *true* answer for a specific product requires the equivalent of at least a master's thesis research in economics. It is not that people cannot think of explanations on the spot, but in reality, these often turn out to be just-so stories.

What we can know, as cooks, is what qualities of manuka honey exist and get sold, no matter for what price. Also, we can suggest signs that may be evidence for good quality honey when you choose which one to buy. So you can build a question along these lines. We even have a tag for it, [ingredient-selection](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ingredient-selection). Don't ask for price, or "is this one honey good", but something like "how do I recognize good quality manuka honey".